Snap usage with for in ModelBuilder in ArcGIS
Did anyone manage to use the Snap tool with iterators?
I could not find what I should write the expression and code block for defining the variables of snap tool.

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. All Questions should always specify the exact software in use within the body of the Question. You have this tagged with ArcGIS 10.2 which is ancient (released 11 years ago, and retired more than 5 years ago) -- It's unlikely anyone here would have that available.  The Question also references a link, which is not present.
